# plone: transfered site does not load css

Tags: plone

I was asked to help with the transfer from a site of which the server died.

The site runs plone 4.1.
I copied the whole buildout directory to my local computer and did a buildout. The resulting site runs fine.
A screenshot of it can be seen here: http://snag.gy/p3TcK.jpg

I then copied the local buildout folder to the new server, and did a buildout.
here the site does not load any css and produces the following sight: http://snag.gy/0uNqM.jpg

has anybody an idea, what could be the reason?

to my mind the environment is very similar on both computer. The only real difference I see, is that the "failing" server uses a slightly older python
failing:
Zope Version

(2.13.10, python 2.7.6, linux2)
Python Version

2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) [GCC 4.8.2]
good:
Zope Version

(2.13.10, python 2.7.10, linux2)
Python Version

2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) [GCC 5.2.1 20151010]

thanks
robert

Comment: Is there a load balancer or reverse proxy between you and Zope? Anything that would put the Zope instances at a different location than the address you're querying?

If not, At the root of the Zope install (through the Zope Management Interface), look for a Virtual Host Monster object (often named virtual_hosting) and check its mappings tab. Let us know what you find.

Comment: I also suspect a Virtual Host Monster issue. You can verify this by checking the urls of the css files included in the source code of the page. Other suggestions could come from the network tab panel of your browser inspector tool.

Answer (score 1):

With this lack of information is hard to tell you whats wrong, but the following pointers may help you.

First the python version should not be an issue.

Trouble shooting:

- Copy the local buildout folder means, you also copied all **eggs**? This is considered a bad idea. You need to copy only the parts, which will not be generated by the buildout (var, buildout.cfg, bootstrap.py, etc.) DO NOT AND NEVER copy (eggs, develop-eggs, .installed, parts, etc.) from one to another machine. This is my best bet :-)
- Check what happens with the missing CSS files? (use Chrome/Safari/FF to debug)

  - No error? --> Try running your site on the Server in debug mode. Probably one CSS file has issues
  - Not in DOM at all? --> This means your server installation definitely differs from your local installation.
- In case of a diazo theme, there may be issues with lxml/xslt (Error log should help you in this case).
- Do you have all necessary system libs installed? --> http://docs.plone.org/manage/installing/installation.html#install-the-operating-system-software-and-libraries-needed-to-run-plone

Further, please extend your question with more infos about your environment.

- Installed addons
- Diazo, or old style theme.
- Error log
- What you tried so far to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

thanks,
the isue was that a diazo rule pointed to a bad url.

Why it did work locally, I wonder ..

robert